# How to align layers by the upper left corner rather than being centered?

Tags: gimp

Using GIMP I am able to load a number of files with File>Open-as-Layers, then File>Export as an animated GIF. The layers are automagicly centered. I would like them to be aligned by the upper left corner instead.

I assume that would need to be handled when the files are first loaded but the only option on the Open-as-Layers was to specify which files to load.

Answer (score 0):

If the frame files have filenames containing numbers of sequential frames (for example `frame01.png`, `frame02.png` and so on) you could use GIMP Animation Package plugin to automatically convert them into a GIF.

Just install GAP, open the first frame and choose *Video* → *Frames to Image*. You'll be asked to configure frame times, looping, blending etc. Frames will be aligned to top left corner by default.